# Regular Expression Not Returning Array

Tags: c#, regex

I have inherited a piece of software which has some regular expression code in it.

At the moment, the code is returning a single long string instead of an array of 3 strings.

I just cannot seem to fix it as it looks right.

This is the code:

```
public class EntryLine
{
   public string[] Numbers;
}

var result = (from l in Regex.Replace("060926404345061418284348021622343942", "(.{1,2})", "$1").Split(' ')
                      select new EntryLine() { Numbers = Regex.Replace(l, "(.{2})", "$1").Split(' ') }).ToArray();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is what you are trying to do something like this `var nums = Regex.Matches("060926404345061418284348021622343942", "(.{1,2})").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();`

Comment: The code doesn't do anything, it replaces every two characters with themselves and then splits around a single space which also doesn't do anything because there isn't any spaces ?!!

Comment: thanks - I can now see that the code does nothing. my apologies... it appears that it's the function that creates the "060926404345061418284348021622343942" that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't make any sense.

```
Regex.Replace("060926404345061418284348021622343942", "(.{1,2})", "$1")
```

is a no-op - every group of two characters (or the last single character) is replaced by itself. The same goes for the next regex.

The following `.split(" ")` is also a no-op because there aren't any spaces to split on.

What are you trying to achieve?